# Add node with no title

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to let users create elements with no title.

In this particulary case, I would like them to enter a registration number, as you can imagine there's no need for a title right here.

How can I remove it from the creation page (node/add/node-type),  so I can only see the fields I want (not the title)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Automatic Node Titles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module does that.

Comment: Is all I needed. Although I think it's a workaround. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't submit a node without a title. You can use the [Auto Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module which doesn't completely remove the title field, Instead hides the title field and fills it with a given pattern.

Another way is to rename the title field to *Registration Number*, if you are using a text field for registration numbers,

Comment: I think this is best approach to solve this, does not require extra module, saves you creating a field.